# unable to select an item in cxImageComboBox1

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I added 3 items to cxImageComboBox1.

Assigned ImageList1 for the images.
Looks like this :

[image]

At runtime it displays images correctly. However only the first image (1) can be selected. I can not select the '2' or '3' :

[image]

Why wont it allow me to make the selection ? I do not understand.
Also it wont allow me to set the ImageIndex to -1 so it displays empty at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only set the **descriptions**. Try also setting the **values**.

Comment: Thank you. I didnt know you had to do that as well.

Comment: Yeah, that's the essential part. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must make unique value for every Items (Set Value 1,2,3)